# Kafka Topic Name in parameterized way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

```
val envi = "test1"

val Q_stream = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Kafka.Server")
    .option("subscribe", "topicname_${envi}")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
    .option("kafka.group.id", "myConsumerGroup")
    .load()
    .toDF()
    .select(col("key").cast("string").as("key"), col("value").cast("string"))


val value2Stream = Q_stream
    .filter(col("key") === "AB")
    .select(functions.from_json(col("value"), ABSchema).as("value"))
    .select("value.*")

value2Stream.writeStream.format("orc")
.option("metastoreUri", "hive.warehouse.metastoreUri")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/strlocation_${envi}/AB/checkpointtest1")
.option("path", "/tmp/str2/AB")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 Seconds"))
.partitionBy("jobid")
.start()
```

This code is working fine, but it failed when we are subscribing another topic. So requirement is when submit a job in test1 environment, then kafka topic should subscribe topicname_test1. And when submit a job in test2 environment, then kafka topic should subscribe topicname_test2.

**I tried this also which is not working.**

```
var isQA: Boolean = false
if (args.length > 0) {
isQA = args(0).toString.trim().toUpperCase == "Q"
getEnvironment = args(1).toString.trim().toUpperCase == "TESTDEVC"
}
var env = ""
var envi = ""
if (isQA) {
      configManager.setup("test.conf")
      env = "QA"
      if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC") { // TODO: implement
        envi = "TESTDEVC"
      } else if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC1") {
        envi = "TESTDEVC1"
      }else if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC2") {
        envi = "TESTDEVC2"
      }
      else {
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown environment")
      }
    }

val Q_stream = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Kafka.Server")
    .option("subscribe", "test_${envi}")
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
    .option("kafka.group.id", "myConsumerGroup")
    .load()
    .toDF()
    .select(col("key").cast("string").as("key"), col("value").cast("string"))


val value2Stream = Q_stream
    .filter(col("key") === "AB")
    .select(functions.from_json(col("value"), ABSchema).as("value"))
    .select("value.*")

value2Stream.writeStream.format("orc")
.option("metastoreUri", "hive.warehouse.metastoreUri")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/strlocation_${envi}/AB/checkpointtest1")
.option("path", "/tmp/str2/AB")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 Seconds"))
.partitionBy("jobid")
.start()
```

Comment: What was the stacktrace for the failure ?

Comment: I am first testing in spark-shell. It is not taking another parameter. I believe , we have to apply in loop or if condition but if is getting difficult when we are trying to implement in streaming.

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe` option can only be provided once, and that's not how you do string interpolation in Scala. You're missing the leading `s`

Sounds like you just need to check your environment, which is a scala question, not related to Spark...

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var env: String
    if (getEnvironment() == "env1") {  
        env = "test1" 
    } else if (getEnvironment() == "env2") { 
        env = "test2" 
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown environment") 
    } 

    val Q_stream = spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Kafka.Server")
        .option("subscribe", s"topicname_${env}")

... 
} 

def getEnvironment() : String {
// TODO: implement 
}
```

Same applies for checkpointLocation

Alternatively, you can provide the environment or topic suffix as an argument to `spark-submit` - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Comment: var isQA: Boolean = false
if (args.length > 0) {
isQA = args(0).toString.trim().toUpperCase == "Q"
isQA = args(1).toString.trim().toUpperCase == "TESTDEVC"
}
var env = ""
var envi = ""
if (isQA) {
      configManager.setup("test.conf")
      env = "QA"
      if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC") { // TODO: implement
        envi = "DEVC"
      } else if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC1") {
        envi = "QA2"
      }else if (getEnvironment == "TESTDEVC2") {
        envi = "QA3"
      }
      else {
        throw new RuntimeException("unknown environment")
 }}

Comment: This code is not working. I want that argument which we would pass in spark-submit should come in  getEnvironment which is TESTDEVC

Comment: I don't understand your question. And I cannot read that code since it's not formatted. Any arguments after the jar are passed to the main function https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit  You appear to be assigning the same variable to two different arguments

Comment: I edited my question again, please check it once

Comment: Your `getEnvironment` is a boolean. It'll never equal a string. The answer given uses a function, not a variable