# Add prefix/suffix on kafka topic at runtime

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

So here suppose if environment is TEST1 and topic name is BENEFIT then it should return like TEST1_BENEFIT

```
object hello {
def Complete (jobId: BigInt, tableName: String, topic: String = configManager.getString("Kafka.Completion.Table.Topic")): Unit = {
val kafkaServer = configManager.getString("Kafka.Server")
val props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer)
props.put("key.serializer")
props.put("value.serializer")
props.put("batch.size", "1")
props.put("acks", "all")
val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, value)
producer.send(message)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72658522/kafka-topic-name-in-parameterized-way), use [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) or concatenation

```
val message = new ProducerRecord[String, String](s"${environment}_${topic}", key, value)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer : This looks good. We can do in this  way. But how to call the environment name if don't know its value. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please help how to create global variable. As the above problem , I believe, resolve only by calling global variable.  So wherever file I assigned that variable we can call it in environment.

Comment: @dataeng I don't understand the question. You can add a parameter to `def Complete` for some `environment: String`; it doesn't need to be "global". Ideally, your `configManager` would providing that value, if that does what I think it does

Comment: @dataeng I am not. You said your question that "suppose if environment is TEST1", and now you are saying `environment` you "don't know its value" ? I don't have your full code, so I cannot tell you how to define your own variables, but like I said, `val environment = ConfigManager.getString("environment")` seems like a good place to start